# Get amount of users with no entries in foreign table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to find the amount of Users that have no Documents

Something in the line of:

```
User.includes(:documents).where("document.count == 0").count
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to find the amount of Users that have no Documents

This should do

```
User.includes(:documents).where("documents.user_id IS NULL").count
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
users = User.all.select do |user|
  user.documents.any? ? false : true
end

count = users.count
```